# How can I submit an Apache Storm topology to a Storm cluster?

Tags: apache-storm

I'm following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/storm/apache-storm-develop-java-topology

What I've done so far is

- maven setting
- vi *.java files (in `src/main/java/com/microsoft/example` directory)

  - RandomSentenceSpout.java
  - SplitSentence.java
  - WordCount.java
  - WordCountTopology.java
- mvn compile
- `jar cf storm.jar *.class` (in `target/classes/com/microsoft/example` directory)

  - RandomSentenceSpout.class  SplitSentence.class  WordCount.class  WordCountTopology.class
  - The above 4 files were used to make `storm.jar` file

Then, I tried

```
storm jar ./storm.jar com.microsoft.example.WordCountTopology WordCountTopology
```

and

```
storm jar ./storm.jar WordCountTopology
```

, but both of these failed, saying:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.microsoft.example.WordCountTopology

or

> Error: Could not find or load main class WordCountTopology

According to a [document](https://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Command-line-client.html), it says

> Syntax: storm jar topology-jar-path class ...
>
> Runs the main method of class with the specified arguments. The storm
> jars and configs in ~/.storm are put on the classpath. The process is
> configured so that StormSubmitter will upload the jar at
> topology-jar-path when the topology is submitted.

I cannot find where to fix.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your jar file does not contain class WordCountTopology. You can check it with `jar tf storm.jar | grep WordCountTopology`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your jar does not contain a Manifest file  which keeps information about the main class.

Try including the Manifest file or you can run the below java command to include the Manifest file

Hope this works!

```html
jar cvfe storm.jar mainClassNameWithoutDotClassExtn *.class
```